# PLEASE HELP ME RECOVER MY DATA FROM AN FFFFFFFFFFFFFF PARTITION :(

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos, partition, ssd

i had mojave on my macbook pro and my work softwares weren't too compatible so i decided to downgrade WITH keeping the mojave partition that has 367 gb and use a usb stick to boot into recovery mode and install El capitan on the smaller 132 gb partition ....Someone out there skillful to help me recover my very important data ?? much appreciated <3[image]

[image]r.com/AmMUn.jpg

Comment: "Very important data" usually means that you have a backup, so restoring from such might be easier than trying to fix the partition table. If you want to try nevertheless, there are a lot of questions with answers on this already on the site.

Comment: nohillside even my back up external seagate 4tb got messed up :( i dont think my question is a duplicated subject....

Comment: Did you look at the other questions about FFFFF, there are several. Might very well be that your case is different, but that‘s impossible to tell without details. So please edit the question to explain which answers you‘ve looked at and why they don‘t solve your problem.